# Should I give all my relations associations through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database

Is it considered bad form to give the relations between my tables a `:through` association? e.g. if I had multiple `show`s each of which has only one performer, and I want to give be able to say something like `aShow.performer`, is that sufficient reason to set up a `:through` association? Is there a down side to setting up this association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your schema is as simple as you have indicated, I'm not sure why you would need `:through`.  Instead you would have:

Show:

```
has_many :performers
```

Performer:

```
belongs_to :show
```

In this design, Performer would have `show_id` as a foreign key while Show would have no foreign key to Performer.  The `:through` becomes necessary when you want to do something nested:

Finger:

```
`belongs_to :performer`
```

Performer:

```
belongs_to :show
has_many: fingers
```

Show:

```
has_many :performers
has_many :fingers, through: :performers
```

This will allow you to refer to all of the fingers of the performers that are associated:  `Show.first().fingers`, rather than having to get the performers first.

Really this is just syntactic sugar to take all of the work out of the relations.